# How to render more than once when using observeEvent in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am using `shiny` in R and want to render more than once when using `observeEvent` in server.R

I don't understand why this does not work:

```
library(shiny)

my_UI <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(actionButton("test", "test")),
  fluidRow(textOutput("out"))
)

my_Server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$test, {
    output$out <- renderText("waiting")
    Sys.sleep(2)
    output$out <- renderText("done")
  })
}

shinyApp(my_UI, my_Server)
```

I also tried:

```
library(shiny)

my_UI <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(actionButton("test", "test")),
  fluidRow(textOutput("out"))
)

my_Server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$test, {
    output$out <- renderText("waiting")
  })
  observeEvent(input$test, {
    Sys.sleep(2)
    output$out <- renderText("done")
  })
}

shinyApp(my_UI, my_Server)
```

In both cases, only the latter message is rendered...
What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't give you solution for each line render in one observeEvent, but if you just want show loading/calculation progress, you can use

> withProgress()

so app can be like this:

```
library(shiny)

my_UI <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(actionButton("test", "test")),
  fluidRow(textOutput("out"))
)

my_Server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$test, {
    withProgress(
      message = 'Calculation in progress',
      detail = 'This may take a while...', value = 0, {
        incProgress(1/2, message = "Step 1")
        Sys.sleep(2)
        # Do some stuff, load, calculate, etc
        incProgress(1/2, message = "Step 2")
      })
  })
}

shinyApp(my_UI, my_Server)
```

Comment: Thank you. So it is a limitation of `shiny`... Though, `withprogress()` is a fair workaround for me =]

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with Shiny, because only the latest output value will be used.

You can do it with javascript, but you have probably better options, i.e. `withProgress` as feniw_fx mentionned

```
library(shiny)
my_UI <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(
      "function test() {
      document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = 'waiting';
      setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = 'done'}, 2000);}"
  )),
  fluidRow(actionButton("test", "test", onclick = "test()")),
  fluidRow(textOutput("out"))
)

my_Server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(my_UI, my_Server)
```